# Can I force the type of a variabile in a extended class to a subtype in Java?

Tags: java, extends

Having this:

```
public class A{}
public class B extends A{}
public class C{
    protected A x;
}
```

Is there any way to create a class D which extends C such that the type of `x` must be `B` in all D's instances? Note that C is a class I'm writing, so I could edit it on purpose to accomplish D needs.

Comment: You can use generics for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic type

```
public class C<T>{
    protected T x;
}

public class D extends C<SomeConcreteType>{
     //x will be SomeConcreteType
}
```

Comment: Nice, it didn't think to do so.

Comment: However, this solution doesn't force the variable x in C to be of type A. I mean, it's something, but it's not a complete solution. 
Also, I doesn't look a good use of generics to me, since class C is not made to have a generic type.

Comment: You can narrow generic types - how about `T extends A`?